# Using sed to print the lines starting with two different patterns

Tags: linux, sed

I am already using the following `sed` command to print the lines starting with a certain word (e.g. A), however, couldn't figure out how to use this command to print the lines that start either with A or B.

```
sed -n '/A/p' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an alternative:

```
sed -n '/A\|B/p' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

Note that this does not only print lines starting with A or B, but lines *containing* A or B. To make it really match at the beginning of a line, you have to add the anchor `^`:

```
sed -n '/^A\|^B/p' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

which is equivalent to

```
sed '/^A\|^B/!d' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

which means "Delete lines that do not start with A or B".

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `/^A\|B/p`?

Comment: +1. Another approach is to write `sed -n '/^A/p; /^B/p' 1.txt > 2.txt`.

Comment: @JimGarrison: On my `sed` (GNU sed 4.1.5), it definitely has to be `/^A\|^B/p`. Does yours behave differently?

Comment: @JimGarrison: `/^A\|B/` means "starts with A or contains B anywhere". You probably had `/^\(A\|B\)/` in mind.

Comment: @ruakh `^` does not bind to the right - `/^A\|B/` matches any line starting with `A` or `B` on GNU sed, at least on RHEL 6.3 (sed 4.2.1)  and Cygwin (sed 4.2.2).

Comment: @JimGarrison: Oh really? Try `echo cB | sed -n '/^A\|B/p'`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n '/^[AB]/p' 1.txt > 2.txt
```